# EaselJS tick event delta property not propagating to children

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I am just starting out with EaselJS and I am running into my first hurdle. I have extended the Container object to create a new class called Egg:

```
(function() {

var Egg = function(color, x, y, cY) {
  this.initialize(color, x, y, cY);
}
var e = Egg.prototype = new createjs.Container(); // inherit from Container

e.Container_initialize = e.initialize;
e.initialize = function(color, x, y, cY) {

  this.Container_initialize();

  this.circle = new createjs.Shape();
  this.circle.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
  this.circle.x = x;
  this.circle.y = y;
  this.addChild(this.circle);

  this.changeY = cY;

  this.addEventListener("tick", this.handleTick);

}

e.handleTick = function(event) {
  console.log(event.delta); // undefined!
}

window.Egg = Egg;

}());
```

And I am initializing like this:

```
var stage, timeCircle;

function init() {

  stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");

  timeCircle = new createjs.Shape();

  createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

  var egg = new Egg("red", 50, 50, 100);
  stage.addChild(egg);

  var egg2 = new Egg("blue", 100, 50, 50);
  stage.addChild(egg2);

}


function tick(event) {
  stage.update(event);
}
```

In the Egg handleTick function, when I log out the event.delta property, I get "undefined". I thought that if I passed in the event through the stage.update call then it would propagate to the objects on the stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ticker`'s tick-event is a little different from a `DisplayObject`'s(or the `Stage`'s) tick-event.
See here: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#event_tick

So in your case this should probably work:

```
e.handleTick = function(event) {
    console.log(event.params[0].delta);
    //params is all the parameter that you use in stage.update(p1, p2, ...);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand how the event parameters were passed to the DisplayObject as "params" - thanks!

Comment: As a follow up for anyone that stumbles onto this answer: EaselJS v0.8.0 now exposes `delta` on display list tick events to avoid this confusion.